# Морфемный разбор слова «вставлю»

Tags: словообразование, морфология, суффиксы

*В-ставл-ю*

Почему "Л" относится к корню, а не к суффиксу?

Answer (score 2):

Это вопрос исторического чередования согласных **в//вл, б//бл, п//пл, м//мл** в корне слова.

Русским словам несвойственны такие сочетания, как *пю, бю, вю, кю* и др. Такие сочетания характерны для заимствованной лексики (пюре, пюпитр). В русских словах буква Л как бы мягкий мостик между твёрдыми Б, В, П, М и буквой Ю в глаголах 1 лица единственного числа: *люблю, леплю, ловлю, приемлю, ставлю*. В других личных формах Л исчезает: *любишь, лепит, ставят* и т.п.

Не путаем с суффиксом -Л- глаголов в форме прошедшего времени (*ходил*).

Comment: @Екатерина - мостик-то он мостик, можете и так назівать, но вопрос стоит о том, чем руководствуются грамматисті и авторі словарей, относя его к корню, а не к суффиксу.

Comment: @behemothus  Сложно всё очень с этой йотированной палатализацией). Не каждый поймёт. Я решила, что человеку нужно объяснение попроще). Кажется, у меня получилось слишком просто, совсем не научно). Ну, не мой день).

Comment: @Екатерина - да нет, ничего ненаучного там нет. А просто - єто только плюс. Вернее сказать, Было бы плюсом. Я не об этом. Вы, похоже, не на тот вопрос отвечаете. Вопрос о членении на морфы, а вы о происхождении, фонетическом генезисе.

Answer (score 0):

Это вполне оправдано происхождением звука.

Л - здесь чисто фонетическое явление, не имеющее морфемно-грамматической мотивации. По отношению к корню этот звук - эпитеза (вставной звук в конце слова или морфа), ко всему слову - эпентеза (аналогичный по образованию звук в конце слова).

Такие "вставные" звуки обычно и возникают на стыке морфем, в нашем случае - корня и приставки, но обычно предопределяется фонетикой первого морфа. В нашем случае это переход Л<Й под влиянием согласного в конце корня. Сравните: ***пить-пью [п'йу]***, но ***любить-люблю [л'убл'у]***. В последнем случае появление эпентатического звука определяется звуком "Б" - конечным согласным корня. И хотя появление эпентезы данного типа не императивно даже в таких условиях (***грести-гребу***, не *"греблю"*, ***пороть-порю***, не *порлю*), все-таки прослеживается четкое частотное условие её возникновения - корень оканчивающийся на согласный, а приведенные примеры стоит рассматривать скорее как ислючения.

К суффиксу -Л-, известному по прошедшему времени современного русского глагола, этот звук не имеет никакого отношения. В таких условиях вполне логично отнести данный вставной звук -Л- именно к корню.

--

Тут возникла дискуссия по поводу того фонетическое ли это явление.
 Честно говоря, от доводов оппонента у меня просто волосы дыбом встали (все три))).

Все что могу сделать - дать цитату, пусть и не из самого авторитетного источника, но  очень к месту.

> Первоначально расселение славянских племен в западном и восточном
>   направлениях привело к формированию двух этнических подгрупп, западной
>   и восточной, и соответственно двух диалектов праславянского языка,
>   которые характеризовались рядом ***фонетических*** особенностей (рис. 3).
>   Восточному диалекту были свойственны такие черты, как ж, чна месте
>   *dj, *tj (сажа < *sadja; свеча <*svētja);***вставочный л (l-epenthetikum)на месте *bj, *pj, *mj  (люблю, вопль, земля)***;утрата
>   взрывного в сочетаниях *dl, *tl (мыло, рыло);изменение сочета-ний *gv,
>   *kv в*cv, *zv (цвет, звезда)...

[БГПУ, Сравнительно-сопоставительная грамматика русского и белорусского языков.](https://elib.bspu.by/bitstream/doc/44656/1/%D0%A3%D0%9C%D0%9A_%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.pdf)

То есть. Ни о каком явлении из "СРЛЯ" речи не идет. Эта такая седая древность, что страшно вспомнить.
Во-вторых, явление недвусмысленно названо фонетическим. 
И в-третьих, дает примеры явления не только на стыке корня и суффикса.

Ну а то, что кому-то пришло в голову отказать рассмотриваемому явлению в праве называться фонетическим... Чередование К/Ч на том же стыке корня и суффикса - оно как, тоже "не фонетическое"? А ведь ситуация совершенно аналогичная. Фонетический закон, по которому заднеязычные перед гласными переднего ряда обязательно палатализовались давно перестали действовать (таких законов было несколько, но это совершенно не принципиально в нашем контексте, все они перестали быть продуктивными), однако в ряде случаев возникает рефлекс в сравнительно молодых словах: *обеспечение*, *обручиться*, *раскулачивать* и даже разговорное *"глючить"* (вот уж слово, которому явно не больше лет, чем нам). Проявляется именно на стыке корня и суффикса - и нигде более. Но к собственно грамматике, морфемному разбору, понятно, отношения этот факт не имеет.

Comment: Было бы хорошо уточнить, про историю или синхронию вы говорите: "Л - здесь чисто фонетическое явление" и т. д.

Comment: @Aer - *про историю или синхронию...* - да тут так вопрос-то и не стоит. И в историческом плане, и в любом другом появление этого  "Л"  - как и вообще всех подобных звуков (протез, эпентез, эпитез) - объясняется чисто фонетическими процессами. Они так и вводятся как фонетические,  к грамматике/морфологии отношения не имеющие. *Появление протетических звуков может быть вызвано **фонетическими причинами разного характера**, в частности, протеза может возникать для облегчения произношения*. (Вики). Все. **Фонетические разного характера**  Какое отношение это имеет к синхронии или диахронии?

Comment: Если вы относите появление _л_ в рассматриваемом случае в СРЛЯ к фонетическим явлениям, то это ошибочно. Вот.

Comment: *Если вы относите появление л в рассматриваемом случае в СРЛЯ к фонетическим явлениям* - а каким же еще? Грамматики тут нет.

Comment: Тогда будьте добры, объясните отсутствие отражения этого "фонетического" явления в словах СРЛЯ _бюро, парфюмер, волапюк, мюзикл_... Более того, показательно, что вы определяете чисто "фонетическое" явление через понятия "морф", "корень слов", "стык морфем", что, конечно, указывает на не-фонетический характер оного.

Comment: @Aer извининте, я вынужден вам отказать вам в подобной просьбе. Ибо подобнуя постановка вопроса считаю недопустимой в принципе. Объяснять положено факт, а не отсутствие факта. Это во-первых. А во-вторых, где я говорил что-то о словах, ками приведенных? Какое они вообще отношение имеют е моей мысли?

Comment: Попрошу вас не удалять ссылку на обсуждение в чате: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106420/discussion-between-behemothus-and-aer. Я привёл там свои доводы, а вы лишили читателей возможности с ними ознакомиться. Это по меньшей мере некрасиво.

Comment: @Аеr, я удалил **свою** ссылку, которая появилась ошибочно - раньше,  чем я написал последний комментарий. Вы её скорее всего даже и не видели. ***Вашу*** ссылку я не удалял, ***я физически не могу это сделать, я не модлератор***.  Давайте уже кончать эти надуманные претензии. А то ведь подумают, что так всем можно отстаивать свою позицию, не только модераторам.

Comment: Я и не пишу, что вы удалили какую-то мою ссылку: вы сначала предложили перейти в чат, а потом добавили два ответа, ссылка на чат была удалена. Я перенес эти два ответа в чат, так что давайте продолжать обсуждение там.